# Dynamic LINQ with other databases

Tags: sql, linq, dynamic-linq

Are there any free (gratis) providers for databases other MS SQL (e.g. MySQL or SQLite) that work with LINQ and support dynamic SQL query generation? E.g. `table.Count()` generates something like `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table` and doesn't first load the whole table and then count the rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the **DBLinq project:** http://code.google.com/p/dblinq2007/

DbLinq is THE LINQ provider that allows to use common databases with an API close to Linq to SQL. It currently supports (by order of appearance): MySQL, Oracle, PostgreSQL, SQLite, Ingres, Firebird

Whether these providers execute `Count()` in the way you describe depends on the quality of the provider, I suppose.  Presumably some effort is made at optimization.

See also http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx

Comment: There isn't any indication on the DBLinq page, whether it is stable, last release is one year old (although the SVN was last updated yesterday). If there isn't anthing better, I will try this.

Answer (score 1):

Check out [ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399572.aspx). It supports MySQL via ADO.NET data providers and LINQ to Entities (similar to LINQ to SQL). Being a Microsoft tool, it has good Visual Studio integration and support.

Can you also explain why you want to support these databases?

Comment: You didn't answer my question: do those providers support dynamic SQL generation?

I want to use other databases, because many of the free ASP.NET hosts (yes, I don't want to pay for my personal web projects) run on Linux and Mono with MySQL as DB.

Comment: Looking at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42212/how-can-i-use-linq-with-a-mysql-database-on-mono and the documentation (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-net.html) it seems the MySQL Connector/NET has LINQ and Mono support. The Entity Framework though isn't supported on Mono (yet, see http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)...

Comment: EF will do what you ask in the question (convert Count() to SELECT COUNT(*), yes.

Answer (score 0):

NHibernate supports [multiple databases](https://www.hibernate.org/361.html) and has a recently-released [Linq provider](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/07/26/nhibernate-linq-1.0-released.aspx).

Comment: Their LINQ provider seems to be quite problematic, they are saying that version 2 shoud be much better.